# python 3 (Qt) [Errno 13] Permission denied. How to get folders path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, permission-denied

I'm building small desktop app. All i need  is to get folders path and put it in textEdit widget. From there I need to run some "scan" function through all files that are sitting in that folders path. But all I get is this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/dava8001/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/test-scan1/images'.
```

Any advise?

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QLineEdit, QToolTip, QMessageBox, QProgressBar, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QBasicTimer
import sys
import os

class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title = "Barcode Scanner"
    self.top = 100
    self.left = 100
    self.width = 680
    self.height = 500

    self.InitWindow()

def InitWindow(self):
    self.button = QPushButton("Choose Folder Path", self)
    self.button.move(100, 150)
    self.button.resize(150, 50)
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.getFolder)

    self.btnScan = QPushButton("Scan", self)
    self.btnScan.move(450, 150)
    self.btnScan.resize(150, 50)
    self.btnScan.clicked.connect(self.scan)

    self.btnClose = QPushButton("Close", self)
    self.btnClose.move(450, 400)
    self.btnClose.resize(150, 50)
    self.btnClose.clicked.connect(self.CloseApp)

    self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
    self.textEdit.move(100, 200)
    self.textEdit.resize(500, 30)


    self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
    self.pbar.setGeometry(100, 350, 532, 25)

    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("barcode.png"))
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.top,self.left, self.width, self.height)
    self.show()

def scan(self):
    self.completed = 0
    while self.completed < 100:
        self.completed += 0.0001
        self.pbar.setValue(self.completed)

def getFolder(self):
    """ddir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Open Directory", 
    "C:/Users/dava8001/Desktop/", QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly | 
    QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks)
    ddir = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
    if ddir:
        f = open(ddir, 'r')
        with f:
            data = f.read()
            self.textEdit.toPlainText(data)
    else:
        pass

    self.textEdit(self.getFolder)"""

    name = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Open Directory", "C:/Users/dava8001/Desktop/", QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks)
    file = open(name, 'r')
    self.editor()
    with file:
        text = file.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(text)

def CloseApp(self):
    reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Close Message", "Are you sure you 
    want to close?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: What is the function that is responsible for scanning?

Comment: possible duplicate of :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480795/permission-denied-error-during-initialization

Comment: Scan function is not yet setuped fully. I am using windows 7 in my office.

Comment: Also I shortened folder path to "C:/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program might look something like this:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, 
                             QPushButton, QTextEdit, QLineEdit, QToolTip, 
                             QMessageBox, QProgressBar, QWidget,
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QCoreApplication, QBasicTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal


class AThread(QThread):

    # Use the signals to send the information.
    updateSignal = pyqtSignal(list, int) 

    def __init__(self, folder, allFiles):
        super().__init__()
        self.folder  = folder
        self.cons    = 1 if allFiles<100 else allFiles//100+1
        self.indPbar = 1
        self.ind     = 0
        self.files   = []

    def run(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.folder):
            self.updateSignal.emit(["\n{}:".format(root),], self.indPbar)
            for file in files:
                if self.cons == 1:   
                    self.indPbar += 1
                    self.updateSignal.emit([file,], self.indPbar)
                else:
                    self.files.append("{}".format(file))                    
                    self.ind += 1

                if  self.ind >= 100:
                    self.indPbar += 1
                    self.updateSignal.emit(self.files, self.indPbar)
                    self.ind = 0
                    self.cons -= 1
                    self.files = []
                QThread.msleep(1)
            self.updateSignal.emit(self.files, self.indPbar)
            self.files = []            
        self.updateSignal.emit(self.files, 100)                    


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png"))      # "barcode.png"
        self.setWindowTitle("Barcode Scanner")
        self.resize(500, 400)
        self.allFiles = 0

        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.button = QPushButton("Choose Folder Path")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.getFolder)
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit("E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5") # "C:/Users/dava8001/Desktop"
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.btnScan  = QPushButton("Scan")
        self.btnScan.clicked.connect(
            lambda folder=self.lineEdit.text(): self.scan(self.lineEdit.text()))
        self.btnScan.setEnabled(False)

        self.btnClose = QPushButton("Close")
        self.btnClose.clicked.connect(self.CloseApp)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.pbar     = QProgressBar(self)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(self.button)
        layoutH.addStretch(1)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.btnScan)

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        layoutV.addLayout(layoutH)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.pbar)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.btnClose)

    def scan(self, folder):

        self.btnScan.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread = AThread(folder, self.allFiles)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.closeW)
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.updateSignal.connect(self.update)

    def update(self, texts, val):
        text = "\n".join(texts)
        self.textEdit.append(text)
        self.pbar.setValue(val)

    def closeW(self):
        self.textEdit.append("--- Directory scan complete! ---")
        self.btnScan.setEnabled(True)

    def getFolder(self):
        options = QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly 
        folder  = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 
                            "Open Folder",
                            self.lineEdit.text(),
                            options=options)
        if folder:
            self.pbar.setValue(0)        
            self.lineEdit.setText(folder) 

            self.textEdit.append("\n{}:".format(folder))
            self.allFiles = 0
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
                self.allFiles += len(files)
            self.textEdit.append("    total files: {}".format(self.allFiles))
            self.btnScan.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.textEdit.append("Sorry, choose a directory to scan!")
            self.btnScan.setEnabled(False)

    def CloseApp(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Close Message", 
                                     "Are you sure you want to close?", 
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, 
                                     QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion') 
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, you saved me weeks of struggle! Now i need to understand to learn from your code completely. Thank you very much! All I have to do is to add image scan method so I could get barcode numbers with image names. Thank you!!

Comment: @Aš Vaidas If my code helped you with something, do not forget to mark my answer as useful.